# Add events on same class multiple times

Tags: javascript, beginner

I'm not sure how to title this post as I'm a bit confuse here. My code updates a field in line. It's done in two separate functions. It works well but I wonder if it's possible to handle it in only one function?

Here is the **HTML** code. The `form` is shown on `hover` only and value is updated **on change**.

```
<form class='editable' action="{% url "dashboard_staff:ajax_prestation_length_update" uuid=prestation.uuid %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" class="collapse" name="length" value="{{ prestation.length }}">
    <span>{{ prestation.d_length }}</span>
</form>
```

And the javascript:

```
// Editable in line fields

$('.editable').hover(function () {
    var el_text = this.lastElementChild;
    var el_input = this[1];
    $(el_text).toggleClass('collapse');
    $(el_input).toggleClass('collapse');
});

$('.editable').change(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    var el_text = this.lastElementChild;
    var action = this.action;
    var method = this.method;
    var data = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: action,
        type: method,
        data: data,
    }).done(function (resp) {
        el_text.textContent = resp.data
    });
});
```

I'm not sure it is correct to add multiple functions to a same class as well.

Comment: You can use multiple events of the same element. No problem.

Comment: I wasn't sure since my IDE highlights these as redundant. thanks.